# Multiplexing Go Routine Output using fanIn function

Tags: go

I was trying to implement an example Go code for using returned channels from go routines without any "reading block" in the main function. Here, a fanIn function accepts channels from two other routines and return which got as input.

Here, the expected output is Random Outputs from two inner routines. But the actual output is always one "ann" followed by a "john", not at all random in any case.

Why am I not getting random output?

Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/46CiihtPwD

Actual output:

```
  you say: ann,0 
  you say: john,0
  you say: ann,1
  you say: john,1 
   ......
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    final := fanIn(boring("ann"), boring("john"))

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        fmt.Println("you say:", <-final)

    }
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
}

func boring(msg string) chan string {
    c1 := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; ; i++ {
            c1 <- fmt.Sprintf("%s,%d", msg, i)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)

        }
    }()
    return c1
}

func fanIn(input1, input2 <-chan string) chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for {
            c <- <-input1
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for {
            c <- <-input2
        }
    }()
    return c
}
```

Comment: what led you to believe it *should* be random?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638628/why-is-this-google-i-o-2012-concurrency-example-not-working-as-expected?rq=1

Comment: @JimB I was trying to learn how go routines are called and executed.Here two routines are running parallel.As they are running independently I expected random outputs .But I got same pattern in all run..

Comment: @Marc I had a look on the question you mentioned.The answer was to increase Count of printing to 20 .Here I'm using 100 still not getting random .I think Evan's answer and comment about Sleep is correct answer for this question .It gives more insight..

Comment: @faisalkk: ok, just wondering if there was some erroneous documentation somewhere. Remember these don't technically run independently, they are scheduled by a single scheduler (though that's also an implementation detail). Many things can affect this too, including GOMAXPROCS > 1.

Comment: @faisal k k  in my link he used random sleep times, like oneOfOne suggested

Comment: @Marc My understanding was Sleep put in code for just to feel execution of go routines.Now I understood that Sleep time has a role in randomness.Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @JimB Almost all documents on routine emphasis two things 1.Routines are executed parallel 2.They are independent unit of execution(Channels are used for communication)  .I couldn't find much on how different routines are scheduled in go ( It might not important for me as a developer ) .. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No particular reason, that's just how Go happens to schedule the relevant goroutines (basically, you're getting "lucky" that there's a pattern). You can't rely on it. If you really want an actual reliably random result, you'll have to manually mix in randomness somehow.

There's also the `Multiplex` function from https://github.com/eapache/channels/ (doc: https://godoc.org/github.com/eapache/channels#Multiplex) which does effectively the same thing as your `fanIn` function. I don't think it would behave any differently in terms of randomness though.

Comment: Just to point out that removing the sleep would "fix" the lack of randomness. http://play.golang.org/p/hi8O5GoKsv or sleeping for a random amount of time http://play.golang.org/p/vPi2phRDf5

Comment: Sleeping for a random amount of time would *actually* add real randomness; removing the sleep altogether would just make the dependency on go's scheduler much more obvious (though go is still permitted to schedule them in a deterministic fashion).

In fact, go isn't required to schedule goroutines as soon as they're available, so even a random sleep doesn't technically get you off the hook.

Comment: @Evan Yes ,It worked as expected when Sleep is removed .Thanks for new insight !!